# Trigger for Freeze Button in Salesforce

Tags: user, button, user-record, userrecordaccess

Is it at all possible to create a trigger, workflow rule, process builder, flow, etc that would automatically update a custom field on the User object when the "Freeze" button is clicked on the User's page? I have been down all of the avenues that I have listed above and have hit a wall each time. Since the isFrozen is located on the UserLogin object, I don't believe you can create a trigger that would populate the custom field. I wasn't able to create a formula field either since the isFrozen aspect is not on the User object. I am currently out of ideas at the moment. Any help would be much appreciated or a comment stating that this cannot be done at this point in time so I don't keep banging my head against a wall :) Thank you!

Comment: Would a Scheduable class work?

Answer (score 0):

As long as these updates don't have to be close to real time (meaning: immediate), I would suggest taking the path @NewbieDeveloper27 alluded to and set up [Scheduled Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.192.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) that does the following and runs every night, or whatever interval you deem appropriate:

```
// Retrieve all UserLogin records with SOQL whose SystemModStamp is within the time range since the last run
// Use SOQL to retrieve all User records whose ID match UserLogin.UserID
// Update the custom field on User
```

One thing to be mindful of is Salesforce does not guarantee an exact execution time for Scheduled Apex; it can vary based on load. Therefore, it would be prudent to give the time range a little bit of a buffer to ensure no records are missed by the query.

Comment: is there anything that would perform this function immediately?